# How to divide program - Qt, C++ using mvc logic

Tags: c++, qt

At the beginning I want to tell that I just started learning QT so my knowledge about this is really not deep. I wrote simple tasks management it's a console application of course. I used logic which resembles MVC pattern (controllers, views, actions, models).

For example let's take user login. I create instance of LoginController class, then LoginController creates instance of LoginView who is waiting for user to enter data - login, password. Login and password is saved as LoginView members. Then in LoginController I read this data and passes them as parameters to UserVerificationAction constructor. Constructor of this class saved this data as members of their class. Next in LoginController I calls method of class UserVerification - action() which validates login and password. Then depending on the result of validation I create instance of MenuController or instance of LoginFailiedView. This mechanism is user throughout the program (CreateUserController, AddTaskController) etc. I used virtual methods so MenuController consists of about 20 lines of code and is very easy to read.

I want to use Qt to implement a GUI to be more precise I want to use signals and slots mechanism but I have a dilemma. Maybe it would by better to create a slot in the LoginView class and then creates action instance instead passes entered data to LoginView members and then in LoginController creates instance od action class.  maybe there is a better way to do this. I want you to give me some tips on how I should do it properly

p.s. 
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

In Qt, the concept of a "controller" is slightly blurred. It tends to be part of both the model and view. This does not mean that you can't write a controller to link a model and view logic.

Normally what you will see is a view that emits signals for its actions. And then you wire these either directly into compatible slots on a model or a subclass where you have written your own slots.

If for instance you have a main window. This window might create a model and a view as children. And it may then define slots on the window subclass that wire between the model and view. This means your window is a view and a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides [Model/View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) architecture.
It introduces 3 classes: Model, View and Delegate to store, present and edit data.

I believe that is what you are looking for.